# DELETE query stuck / takes too long

Tags: mysql, database, sql-delete, ibatis, delete-row

I have a big table (almost 2 million records) with 4 columns. All of them are DECIMAL.

```
FIELD1 DECIMAL,
FIELD2 DECIMAL,
FIELD3 DECIMAL,
FIELD4 DECIMAL
```

`FIELD1` is my PK.
`FIELD3` has an INDEX on it.

I have a problem with delete query.

```
DELETE FROM MY_TABLE where FIELD1= <const>;
```

When I'm connecting with ssh to the server machine and running the command - it success!
BUT, I have a java process with iBatis commands, and when running the SAME delete command - it is stuck on the MySQL server on status updating.

```
mysql> show processlist;

| Query   |   278 | updating | delete from MYTABLE where FIELD1 = 'D' |
```

I tried to run optimize table and analyze table but it didn't help.
I tried to recreate the table - but again, it didn't help.

What can be the problem? Why do the delete command succeed directly on the server? and not when executing it with iBatis?

I have another table, having a similar issue - there - the delete on the server, takes short time, but when executing from iBatis it takes 7 sec. to complete!!

What can be the problem?
How can I improve those delete commands???

**Update:**

I wrote a simple java process (opening jdbc connection and executing statement) that execute the same 'delete' command without iBatis - and it runs perfect!!

That's mean that it's something with the iBatis... What can it be?

Comment: check whether your mysql connection object in java is setting any mysql session level variables.

Comment: which storage engine are you using?

Comment: Is the SQL server and the Java application running on the same machine?

Comment: When you suddently have a problem with the same statement from a different session, the problem can be different collations. You have a collation for the client. If that is different between the two connections, MySQL has to do alot more work for certain queries than if it is the same collation as the database has. I'd check for that first. Use "show variables like '%coll%'" to display the settings for both connections.

Comment: - The SQL and the Java are running on the same machine. Yes.

Comment: I changed all collation_connections (server, database, connection) to default collation - utf8 but it didn't help :(